# Displaying ForeignKey data in Django admin change/add page

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm trying to get an attribute of a model to show up in the Django admin change/add page of another model. Here are my models:

```
class Download(model.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey('Task')

class Task(model.Model):
    added_at = models.DateTimeField(...)
```

Can't switch the foreignkey around, so I can't use Inlines, and of course `fields = ('task__added_at',)` doesn't work here either.

What's the standard approach to something like this? (or am I stretching the Admin too far?)

I'm already using a custom template, so if that's the answer that can be done. However, I'd prefer to do this at the admin level.

Comment: Can you please give some more context around the workflow you're trying to achieve in admin? From your post, it sounds like you're editing a Download, and need access to the Task model, is that correct?

Comment: The user requests a download, which is generated and emailed to them by a delayed task (I'm on Windows, so no celeryd, more's the pity)

Comment: Ok, so what do you need to do with the foreign key field?

Comment: display `Download.task.added_at`

Comment: @BrianHicks were you able to pull this off ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you don't need to edit it, you can display it as a readonly field:

```
class DownloadAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('task_added_at',)

    def task_added_at(self, obj):
        return obj.task.added_at
```

Comment: That won't work, as readonly_fields has to be a subset of fields, and I can't add functions to the fields.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. This does work - see [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields).

Comment: Works with fieldsets as well. Kudos.