# Showing model in admin site in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a model, which I want to get shown at Admin site.

**models.py:**

```
class UserDetails(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='userdetails')
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Not set')

def __unicode__(self):
    return u' %s %s ' % (self.user, self.address)
```

**admin.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from index.models import User, UserDetails

class UserDetailsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ("address",)

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserDetailsAdmin)
```

I get an error:

> FieldError: Unknown field(s) (address) specified for User. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class UserDetailsAdmin.

What's wrong?

Comment: The field `address` belongs to `UserDetails` model, not `User`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5684745/2011147) for a workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in **admin.py**

Do like this to `get details of your model attribute` :

```
class UserDetailsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('address', 'user')

admin.site.register(UserDetails, UserDetailsAdmin)
```

`list_display` to control which `fields` are `displayed` on the change list page of the `admin`

Comment: I'm now getting an error: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded' and points to UserDetails model def __unicode__(self) -function. I'll add it to question.

Comment: which python version are u  using : if using Python 3 then use __str__()

Comment: Could it be easy to get password field from default User-model to same UserDetailsAdmin class?

Comment: Yes u can directly do this by putting password field in list_display() if using django abstract user

Comment: Ok, I would like to have an example, but that's maybe already a new question.

Comment: if foreign key and u want to access the F_Key field in your relational model . You can by this :: def get_user_password(self): if self.user:
            return str(self.user.password)  and put get_user_password in list_dsplay()

Comment: whats new question as mentioned in comment:

Answer (score 2):

In your **admin.py**

change

```
admin.site.register(User, UserDetailsAdmin)
admin.site.unregister(User)
```

to

```
admin.site.register(UserDetails, UserDetailsAdmin)
admin.site.register(User)
```