# How to show only related objects in a django admin model

Tags: python, django

In a django admin model with inlines other admin model I want to show only related objects.

simplified example:

```
class Business(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

class BusinessAddress(models.Model):
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business)
    address = models.TextField()

class Pos(models.Model):
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business)
    label = models.TextField()

class PosAddress(models.Model):
    pos = models.ForeignKey(Pos)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address)
```

So I want to retrieve only the related addresses of the selected pos in PosAddress and not all the available addresses

```
class PosAddressAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = PosAddress
    extra = 1

class PosAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Pos
    inlines = [PosAddressAdmin]
```

How is that possible, if it is possible?

Comment: You should be able to achieve something like what you want with InlineModelAdmin:              https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects

Comment: @SimonCrowe unluckly it shows all addresses

Comment: I imagine something like this would work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5684745/9925060